# Probability of points on a circle

Tags: probability

A Rope is 60 meters long.  What is the Probability of having any 2 points with a distance of 20 meters  or less?

(please don"t use calculus since its not in my curriculum

Comment: What _is_ in your curriculum? Is the rope coiled in a circle, or is the rope straight? If the rope is arrange in a circle, how do you compute distance between points, distance of the chord, or distance along the circumference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will assume that the rope is straight. You are choosing two points on it uniformly. The space of all choice is a square, $(0,60) \times (0,60)$. In this square, you are interested in the set described as $\mathcal{S}=\{ (x_1, x_2) \colon \vert x_1 - x_2 \vert < 20  \}$.

The probability then equals to the ratio of the area of $\mathcal{S}$ and the area of the square.

Here is a visual representation of the set:

[image]

You do not need calculus to compute the area of $\mathcal{S}$. You should get the answer of  $\frac{5}{9}$.